# AddSubview and PresentModal Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, view

I am developing an app in which I am using addSubview and PresentModal to present a new view. For the first time presentModal is working fine but when I use presentModal after using addSubview, the previous screen remains on the back and PresentModal comes on half of the screen.How can I fix this issue ?

1)The red one is the view which I am presenting :

**[EDIT]**

`myView=[[View alloc] initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil]`;

```
[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

2)Black one is the screen which I had added as subView:

```
myView1=[[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:myView1.view];
```

[image]

Comment: Do you set `self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen`?

Comment: Can u please post ur whole code for presenting modelVC as well as adding subview?

Comment: Hi,
Make sure that myView in [self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES]; is of type Controller not View.  Write if problem still persists.

Comment: @Nekto - Thanks but it's not working brother :(

Comment: @SuryaKant - Please see the edit part.

Comment: Try this `myView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen`

Comment: @Nekto - :-( Nope !! Same output.

Comment: NSLog `myView.frame` and show it to us.

Comment: Nekto - Don't know why it's showing (null).

Comment: Show me the screen before presenting new view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check frame property in View XIB.
Seems it has different value than expected

Comment: Checked it. It's ok. [0.0,0.0,1024.0,768.0]